# stopImmediatePropagation() not stopping focus after mouse down event

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, web-component

I'm implementing some custom web components. Specifically in this case a button. I have some custom styles for `focus`, `hover` and `mousedown`. I was having trouble preventing the `focus` event from firing after I click the button. I thought using `stopImmediatePropagation()` would prevent the `focus` event from firing after I clicked. However, it wasn't until I used `e.preventDefault()` that the event stopped firing. I'm having trouble understanding why `e.preventDefault();` works but `stopImmediatePropagation()` doesn't. Note that I've excluded some styles and codoe that I don't think is relevant for question.

JS

```
onMouseDown(e) {
    // e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();  //stops default browser action (focus)
}
```

HTML

```
<style>         
    button:focus {
        background-color: #2e7d32;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 4px #84BD00;
        outline: none;
    }

    button:active {
        top: -2px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #33333338;
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
<button ?disabled=${this.disabled} @mousedown="${this.onMouseDown}">
    ${this.innerButtonText}
</button>
```

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` prevents other event listeners(of the same type) from firing not default actions from happening, that is what `preventDefault` is for as it name implies

Comment: This is not limited to Polymer or Web Components; it's what happens with normal buttons too: https://jsfiddle.net/u9omvy3t/.

Comment: @patrick evens if you want to expand on that a little as an answer I will mark it as answered.